# Does not implement interface member - Even though I have implemented the member

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am new to C#. I am adding my own code on top of some sample code I was provided. The `GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles` is my code.

I get the following error message even though I have ensured the method is implemented and the return type is valid.

If I remove the function definition, then the IDE complains the interface is not implemented so I know I'm implementing the interface properly since the IDE isn't complaining.

> Error CS0535  'TradeLogDataService' does not implement interface member 'ITradeLogDataService.GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(string)'   FileInsight FileInsight\TradeLogDataService.cs

This is the interface:

```
using FileInsight.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileInsight.Services
{
    public interface ITradeLogDataService
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<DeepDiveSetting>> GetDeepDiveSettingByLogFolderID(int logFolderID);
        Task<IEnumerable<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles>> GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(string searchString);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that implements the interface:

```
using FileInsight.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileInsight.Services
{
    public class TradeLogDataService : BaseDataService, ITradeLogDataService
    {
        private readonly ITradeLogDBContext _tradeLogDBContext;
        public TradeLogDataService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<WebDataService> logger, ITradeLogDBContext context)
          : base(httpContextAccessor, logger)
        {
            _tradeLogDBContext = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<DeepDiveSetting>> GetDeepDiveSettingByLogFolderID(int logFolderID)
        {
            List<DeepDiveSetting> deepDiveLists = new List<DeepDiveSetting>();
            IEnumerable<DeepDiveSetting> deepDiveSettings = await _tradeLogDBContext.GetDeepDiveSettingByLogFolderID(logFolderID);
            return deepDiveLists.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles>> GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(string searchString)
        {
            List<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles> filterFileRelatedFilesList = new List<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles>();
            IEnumerable<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles> filterFileRelatedFiles = await _tradeLogDBContext.GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(searchString);
            return filterFileRelatedFiles.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple implementations of `FilterFileAndRelatedFiles`? If you go-to-implementation on the one in the interface and the one in the class, do they take you to the same class and file?

Comment: I have recreated the code and it compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VEpAvp (no errors are shown). Perhaps you have a problem with wrong package references or wrong namespaces such that you are not really creating an implementation with the right types. I would try to remove the method and let the IDE re-create it (as a stub). Then look at the differences.

Comment: I did the same, [recreated with fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wMdFtC) and no issues on my side. Another thing  that you could try: from the command line, once on your project or solution folder run: *dotnet build* and check if you get the same error, just in case it might be the IDE not realizing that it should work after you change it.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I let the IDE create the method for me as @HeroWanders suggested but still got the error. I tried dotnet build and it failed because I did not implement the interface member

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have a single implementation of `FilterFileAndRelatedFiles` in my Models folder. You are right the sample code is confusing, but the same method was supposed to be defined in another file that implements ITradeLogDataService. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Close all files, delete the bin and obj directories, restart your IDE and try again!

Answer (score 2):

The issue was a simple/unfun one. The sample code provided had the `TradeLogDataService.cs` file in 2 different locations. The one I implemented the interface in was not the one being used.
Solution was to delete the unused file and implement the interface in the correct file.